# Dates not printed in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

A rather simple example

```
Clear["Global`*"];

data = TimeSeries[{1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 21, 15, 21, 7, 11, 5, 10, 
       18, 73, 38, 103, 21, 35, 31, 46, 31, 35, 94, 71, 48, 78, 71, 74, 
       95, 95, 56, 102, 81, 119, 99, 60, 62, 20, 77, 52, 71, 56, 72, 33, 
       31, 25, 22, 15, 17, 11, 0, 10, 6, 7}, {"Feb 26, 2020"}];

plot = DateListPlot[Accumulate[data], Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal axis contains only two ticks showing only the month but not the dates. Is there a way to control the number of ticks on the horizontal axis and also print the correct values of the dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the ticks for the date axis using `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks ``. This function takes two arguments: the first argument is a list of dates (`{mindate, maxdate}`) and the second is the number of divisions. Optional third argument can be used to specify formatting of date labels.

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[arg1: {mindate, maxdate}, ndivisons, labelformat]
```

Using OP's input data:

```
DateListPlot[Accumulate[data], Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
  {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 9, {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}] &,
   Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Use `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5, "DateShort"] & `` to get

[image]

Comment: In version 12, I cannot reproduce your outputs. In both caes I get the following error message: "A ticks specification in the value of FrameTicks should be None, Automatic, a function, or a list of ticks."

Comment: try if  using  ``System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[data/@{"FirstDate", "LastDate"}, 
      9, {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}] `` works.

Comment: Once more it is not working. See exactly the error messages:  http://www.mediafire.com/file/mt21pbjz78z02kn/test.pdf/file